# Requesting the fritz-box login page via python-requests timeouts inside a docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, python-requests

I have a simple python script which requests the html-content of my fritz-box login page:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://192.168.178.1')
print(r.text)
```

If run that code on my computer it works as expected. But if i create a simple docker container and try to run it, the request timeouts:

```
FROM python:alpine3.17

WORKDIR /usr/src/testcase

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

I can request other network devices in my network and I get the html-content, just the request for the fritz-box times out. Pinging the fritz-box also works. What could be the reason?